# Determine if JOIN resulted in any columns

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I have a sql statement with multiple joins; sometimes there are records resulting from the joins and sometimes not.  It is not an error when the joins are empty.

Is there a way to test whether a particular join is empty without having to trap the exception occurring when a resulting column is not found in the result set?

In other words, if, using JDBC, I execute the following sql statement:

```
select * from AA left outer join BB on AA.keyField = BB.keyField
  where keyField = "123"
```

I would like to know whether that join found any fields without having to trap an exception.  If I then execute the java statement:

```
String valueString = rs.getString("BB.keyField");
```

I get an exception.  I cannot compare rs.getString("BB.keyField") to null, because the getString throws an exception if it did not find any values in the join.

I hope this makes the question more clear, and I apologize for not having expanded on it more in the first place.

Comment: Are you working with SELECT queries or CREATE/UPDATE/DELETE operations? If a JOIN yields in an empty set and that results in an exception, you might have to check the result before invoking any write-based operation.

Comment: Sorry, should have said -- I am selecting values from one or more tables, some of which will have some, some won't.

Comment: I don't think you can avoid not checking for NULL on individual column values.

Comment: I'll do "select * from X join Y on w = z", and I would like to test for whether Y.a was found without having to catch an exception.

Comment: The result set is not empty, because a record was found in the original table.  However, tables joined in the query may not have had any values.

Comment: `if (rs.getObject("Y.a") != null) { /* do something with it */ }`. If you mean you want to avoid this kind of checking, yes there is little you can do to avoid an exception trying to use the value before checking if it is NULL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query won't return columns with such names. It will just use the simple names of the columns (`name`, `keyField`, etc.). Execute the query inside your database query tool, and you'll see which names are assigned to the retrieved columns.

You should never do a `select *`, and always select specific columns. And you should assign aliases to columns if two columns have the same name:

```
select AA.id as aId, AA.name as aName, BB.id as bId, BB.name as bName from ...
```

And, then, you can safely use

```
rs.getString("aId");
rs.getString("bName");
...
```

Also, the exception thrown contains a message, which should help you identify the problem. Read it. And if you don't understand it, post it.